# How to select a ListView item with right click C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, contextmenu

I made a **ListView** that displays images. I added a *MouseDown* event handler and inside I made that:

```
private void FooListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)         
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
       var focusedItem = ltView.FocusedItem;
       if (focusedItem != null && focusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
           cmsIconMenu.Show(FooListView, e.Location);
       else
           MessageBox.Show("Vous n'avez sélectionné(e) aucune icône.");
   }
}
```

because it sucks to left-click and then right-click to save an image directly. Other applications do **not** have this problem. So I need to add some code to check if: the user right clicked on a ListView item, focus it and show a context menu.

***I actually tried***: to check a post that I lost the link but it doesn't do the job.

(Ask me if there is not enough details about my problem).

(It is French because it's a French version of my app)

Comment: The `ListView` control has a `HitTest` method, so start with that.

Comment: Ok but is there any way to make the object selected when right-clicking? I'm going to need this for something `ListView.HitTest(e.Location)`.

Comment: `var lv = sender as ListView; // [...] var item = lv.HitTest(e.Location).Item; if (item != null) { lv.FocusedItem = item; cmsIconMenu.Show(lv, e.Location);}` -- What is `ltView` here? If that's the real name of the ListView Field, change the name of the handler (`FooListView`) in the code you have here, so nobody is wondering whether you're referencing the right Control.

Comment: @Jimi I changed my mind will rewriting the code in this website (don't ask my why I didn't made a copy-paste). I changed the name in the stack overflow code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is the [answer of Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593970/how-to-select-a-listview-item-with-right-click-c-sharp#comment128235480_72593970). So the code for my case is

```
private void FooListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
        var lv = sender as ListView; // [...]
        var item = lv.HitTest(e.Location).Item;
                
        if (item == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Vous n'avez sélectionné(e) aucune icône."); //In English it's You haven't selected any icons (images).
        }
        else
        {
            lv.FocusedItem = item;
            cmsIconMenu.Show(lv, e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Jimi!

You can also replace the name of the method by another name but keep these params (parameters)!